# Can not connect to WiFi from win8, but can from ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I had an eduroam account(from the university) which I was connecting to successfully. Now I moved to another city in Germany and again they have eduroam network. When I am connecting and giving my user and password after 1 second it shows unable to connect to network (can not remember exactly, but user/password is not a problem).

But when I am connecting from ubuntu(same PC of course) I can connect. Any ideas? I badly need Windows :(. Thanks in advance.

I used and did not help:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
netsh int ip reset C:\resetlog.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

have you got any error messages or what is recorded in the Event Viewer(Applications and Services\Microsoft\Windows\Wireless-Auto)?

try to reinstall the network adapter from the device manager.
Run the built-in troubleshoot tool to have a diagnostic.
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Troubleshooting\All Categories\Network Adapter